# Fatal error with zf2 my module in vendor could not be initialized

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2

I trying to create my own module in vendor : vendor/mylib/zf2-auth_manager

error :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager) could not be initialized.' in /home/sandbox/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 189

Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager) could not be initialized. in /home/sandbox/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 189

Module.php :

```
namespace MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

module.config.php :

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager\Controller\DispatchAuthManager'=> 'MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager\Controller\DispatchAuthManagerController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager\routes' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/authManager[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager\Controller\DispatchAuthManager',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager'=>__DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I have try to had my namespace in init_autoloader.php

```
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(
    array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'autoregister_zf' => true,
            'namespaces'=>array(
                'MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager'=> __DIR__ . '/vendor/mylib/zf2-auth_manager'
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

but no change i think it don't find my module, but application.module.php look right

```
'modules' => array(
    'MyLib\ZF2\AuthManager',
    'Application',
),
```

I hope thatsomeone will see what i can not see.

Comment: Are you installing this module using composer, and if so, what does your composer.json autoload configuration look like?

Comment: I did not use composer with this module

Comment: I created a module with composer same error

Comment: I had delete my project and restart with zftool if i create ah module in a folder like mylib/mymodule i have this error without mylib it works. I must do somthings to have a folder for my lib ?

Comment: Why name a module like that? Haven't seen a module that would have it's `Module` class namespaced like that. Have you tried renaming it to simple name e.g., `MyLibAuthManager` and putting it in a matching folder?

Comment: mylib is the name of the folder of all my personal module.

Comment: I have delete and do the projet and module with zftool now it's working. thanks Tim Fountain when you speak about use composer i'm remember Zftool !